# Paypal module for Appcelerator 5.1.2 GA ( iOS, Android )

Tags: android, ios, paypal, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Well, i am looking for some Paypal module (iOS, Android) using the last Titanium Appcelerator SDK 5.1.2 GA and the only modules i found are too old, even TiPaypal has a list of issues that make the module unusuable (and the last hope dies here).

So, my question is, is there a paypal module working with the last sdk ?

thanks in advance..

*(sorry for my bad english)*

Comment: Were you able to use this module for Android: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the ti.paypal version 1.9.0 for iOS and 2.2.3 for Android? You can download from here https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal/releases. If you found any specific problem with the modules you should check if this is a known issue at https://jira.appcelerator.org/. If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: @sharif: Do you know if this PayPal module can be used for Adaptive Payments from Android and iOS app built in Appcelerator Alloy?